# How to deal with NA in the output of the linear regression in R, specifically NA for the three-way interaction terms?

Tags: r, linear-regression, na, interaction

I am running a linear regression with three-way interaction in R
lm(A~X*Y*Z), A=numerical variable, whereas X, Y, Z all are categorical variables with factors.
X=5 factors, Y=2 factors, Z=4 factors. Every time I am running regression the three-way interaction for the last level is missing. For e.g. if I relevel the Z factors, the last is getting dropped in the three-way interaction.

Coefficients: (8 not defined because of singularities). (This is mentioned in the R output)

I have tried using zero intercepts but it did not make any difference
lm(A~0+X*Y*Z) or lm(A~X*Y*Z-1) and all other possible combinations.

lm (A ~ X * Y * Z, data = dat)

X = 5 factors, Y = 2 factors and Z = 4 factors [one of the factors from each variable is acting as base level]

Comment: You simply cannot get a coefficient for every level of a factor. Your model would be over specified and not identifiable. If you need help understanding the statistical reason why, maybe ask for help at [stats.se]. This really isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to use the three categorical variables you could use the mixed effect model package

```
model = lmer(A ~ noise + (1 | Y) + (1 | X) +(1 | Z), data = data)
```

This will give you coefficients for the factors by creating random intercepts but you might need some additional information for the fixed effects aka "noise".

Another approach could be creating dummy variables using the fastdummies package.  This will create a binary variable out of each category that you have.